# Write raw html code inside kotlinx.html DSL

Tags: html, kotlin

I am using Kotlin's html library `kotlinx.html` for dynamic html building.

For debugging proposes I want to write a tag as a raw html. But I can't find any method that would do it. Simple text addition replaces characters like `<` to their codes, so it does not help:

```
StringBuilder().appendHTML().html {
    body {
        +"""
        <form action="http://courier-voddan.rhcloud.com/customer/new_task" method="get">
            get=form
            id=3333
            <button type="submit">ok</button>
        </form>
        """.trimIndent()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simply use `unsafe` inside your tag to prevent HTML encoding.

```
body {
    unsafe {
       +"""<form class="formClass"/>"""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Anything inside `appendHTML` will be encoded. If you want to append raw text you can use `appendln`.

Example from [Streaming · Kotlin/kotlinx.html Wiki · GitHub](https://github.com/kotlin/kotlinx.html/wiki/Streaming):

```
val text = buildString {
  appendln("<!DOCTYPE html>")
  appendHTML().html {
    body {
        a("http://kotlinlang.org") { +"link" }
    }
  }
  appendln()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A (limited) solution would be to hack the DSL and use `onTagContentUnsafe`:

```
this.consumer.onTagContentUnsafe { +"hello"}
```

Every `Tag` has a property `consumer`. This is an object that actually deals with the DOM. In case of HTML generation this object is `HTMLStreamBuilder`. It has a method `onTagContentUnsafe` which gives you the access to the stream builder.

I use a helper function:

```
fun Tag.rawHtml(html: String) {
    assert(this.consumer is HTMLStreamBuilder)
    this.consumer.onTagContentUnsafe { +"$html\n"}
}
```

As @orangy pointed out, this solution works for code generation, but you can't use it for creating JVM DOM, etc. For that there is a ticket: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html/issues/8