# Ktor: How to inject raw html into html DSL

Tags: ktor

just like below, using html DSL to respond, but some fragment came from markdown rendering, I hope raw html text could be part of dom, how could I handle this case.
Of cause, there would have no this problem if using FreeMarker.

```
val rawHtml = renderHtmlFromMarkdown(mdText) // "<p>That came from raw Html</p>"
call.respondHtml(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
    head {
        title {
            +name
        }
    }
    body {
        h1 {
            +"Hello from $name!"
        }
        
        // raw html injection
    }
}
```

expected response:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ktor</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello from Ktor!</h1>
    <p>That came from raw Html</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it! just use `unsafe` extension:

```kotlin
val rawHtml = renderHtmlFromMarkdown(mdText)
call.respondHtml(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
    head {
        title {
            +name
        }
    }
    body {
        h1 {
            +"Hello from $name!"
        }
        unsafe {
            raw(rawHtml)
        }
    }
}
```

and is the same answer of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42906388/1265973)